# Algorithm to make a polygon from an image

Tags: c++, algorithm

I came across an application called PhysicsEditor and it traces images and results in vertices that make up the shape. I'm interested in implementing something that would do this but I'm not sure what type of algorithm can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get all of the points that make up the image (you might need to do this with edge detection or some kind of [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_components_analysis) if you're dealing with bitmaps)

Then you compute a convex hull : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: +1 good to know someone interested in computational geometry :) Maybe opencv can help to in the first stage.

Comment: @Felice, computational geometry is so interesting. And yes, openCV could definitely help.

Comment: What if I only want to do this on an alpha png? then does the first step become easier?

Comment: @Milo, yes it does, if all you want is the non-transparent part of the image to be a solid colour you can use your favourite language to fill all non transparent pixels to a colour of your choice

Comment: What sorts of algorithms are used to do the first step given this then?

Comment: I do not want a flood filled polygon, I want the points that outline it so I can then compute the convex hull and get my polygon.

Comment: @Milo, Then it's still edge detection but it's much simpler that classic edge detection as your boundaries are trivial - one side transparent, one side opaque.

Comment: Could you update your post to include a simple example of this?

Comment: @Milo, I'm not writing an algrithm for you, it's for you to read up and learn about. Your question asked what kinds of algorithms can be used. I answered. Felice also gave you some extra information mentioning that openCV should be helpful to you. Perhaps you should do some more research into libraries that can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: I do not want you to write it, I just either want the name of an algorithm or basic psudocode of one like: check each scanline from left to right until you hit a solid pixel. add to list.

Comment: @ Mark Ransom My only problem is that I have no idea what kind of algorithm I'm looking for. I know it has to do with edge detection, but which algorithm is used whenever you use an alpha png?

Comment: By the way, I said I do not want YOU to write it, not I do not want to write it.

Comment: @Milo, surprising what difference one little word can make. I apologize for reading improperly. I shall delete my comment.